# Why is my jQuery not working/showing when I open my browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#top_message').slideDown(300);
      });
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #top_message {
        height: 50px;
        width: 75%;
        background-color: orange;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top_message">
      We can see you're not logged in. Do you want to <a href="#">sign up</a>?
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I run the code on my browser and it doesn't slide down like it is meant to, what have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Any content in script tag which has a src attribute specified is ignored by browser parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to use the same script to load jQuery and your own code too.

Use two different scripts instead.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top_message').slideDown(300);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, that might of solved one problem but  it still doesn't work :3

Comment: @Bob: Yep, that is your primary problem because it defeats any code you hoped to run. But the other answer shows why your jQuery doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because you're expecting [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) to slide the content down the page (ie change the `top` position).

`slideDown()` animates the `height` to 100%

> The .slideDown() method animates the height of the matched elements. This causes lower parts of the page to slide down, making way for the revealed items.
>
> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is used.

As your element is **already visible, changing from 100% to 100% has no effect**.

Change your code to:

```
$('#top_message').hide().slideDown(300);
```

and you'll see what it does: https://jsfiddle.net/cqwbtdb1/